# Google Charts Multiple Line Charts in Time Series

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization, linechart

How do I make a google charts that has multiple line charts. I know how to do it in chartsjs but it confuses me in google charts. My attempt:

```
   <script>

    google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawCurveTypes);

function drawCurveTypes() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('date', 'X');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Person 1');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Person 2');

        data.addRows(9);

        data.setValue(0, 0, new Date(2010, 1, 1));
        data.setValue(0, 1, 215);
        data.setValue(0, 2, 215);

        data.setValue(1, 0, new Date(2010, 2, 1));
        data.setValue(1, 2, 213);

        data.setValue(2, 0, new Date(2010, 2, 4));
        data.setValue(2, 2, 213);

        data.setValue(3, 0, new Date(2010, 2, 8));
        data.setValue(3, 2, 213);


        data.setValue(4, 0, new Date(2010, 3, 1));
        data.setValue(4, 2, 220);

        data.setValue(5, 0, new Date(2010, 4, 1));
        data.setValue(5, 2, 190);

      var options = {
        {#chartArea:{ width:"100%", height:"100%"},#}
        title: "Persons Performance over Time",
        height: 500,
        width: 1300,
        hAxis: {
          title: 'Time'
        },
        vAxis: {
          title: 'Scores'
        },
        series: {
          1: {curveType: 'function'}
        },

      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }


    </script>
```

But it seems to only make one line chart. I have scores for person 1 and person 2 over time, so its a timeseries data. This is my output goal:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like you have the right idea, you just need to add values for the first series.

here, you've added values for both series.

```
data.setValue(0, 0, new Date(2010, 1, 1));
data.setValue(0, 1, 215);  // series 1
data.setValue(0, 2, 215);  // series 2
```

but since they are both on the same y-axis value, only one is visible.
and no more values for line 1 are ever added, so only a single point is drawn.

```
data.setValue(1, 0, new Date(2010, 2, 1));
data.setValue(1, 2, 213);  // series 2

data.setValue(2, 0, new Date(2010, 2, 4));
data.setValue(2, 2, 213);  // series 2

data.setValue(3, 0, new Date(2010, 2, 8));
data.setValue(3, 2, 213);  // series 2

data.setValue(4, 0, new Date(2010, 3, 1));
data.setValue(4, 2, 220);  // series 2

data.setValue(5, 0, new Date(2010, 4, 1));
data.setValue(5, 2, 190);  // series 2
```

to display series 1, you need to add values for data table column 1.
so it would need to be similar to the following...

```
data.setValue(1, 0, new Date(2010, 2, 1));
data.setValue(1, 1, 200);  // series 1
data.setValue(1, 2, 213);  // series 2

data.setValue(2, 0, new Date(2010, 2, 4));
data.setValue(2, 1, 200);  // series 1
data.setValue(2, 2, 213);  // series 2

data.setValue(3, 0, new Date(2010, 2, 8));
data.setValue(3, 1, 210);  // series 1
data.setValue(3, 2, 213);  // series 2

data.setValue(4, 0, new Date(2010, 3, 1));
data.setValue(4, 1, 207);  // series 1
data.setValue(4, 2, 220);  // series 2

data.setValue(5, 0, new Date(2010, 4, 1));
data.setValue(5, 1, 177);  // series 1
data.setValue(5, 2, 190);  // series 2
```

**EDIT**

the `setValue` method takes the following arguments...

```
setValue(rowIndex, columnIndex, value);
```

the first argument is the row index in the data table to update.
the second argument is the column index in the data table to update.

here, you are adding 9 blank rows...

```
        data.addRows(9);
```

which then requires you to go back and update each row and column individually.

```
    data.setValue(0, 0, new Date(2010, 1, 1));
    data.setValue(0, 1, 215);
    data.setValue(0, 2, 215);
```

but if you already have the values for the row,
you can use the `addRow` method.

so, instead of adding the 9 blank rows, just add the row values one at a time...

```
data.addRow([new Date(2010, 1, 1), 215, 215]);
```

or if all of your data is in the form of an array,
you can add all the rows at the same time using the `addRows` method,
without setting the number of rows...

```
data.addRows([
  [new Date(2010, 1, 1), 215, 215],
  [new Date(2010, 2, 1), 215, 215],
  [new Date(2010, 3, 1), 215, 215]
]);
```

Comment: but one thing I dont undestand is the digits before the actual value, what if I just have date for the date and the actual scores? Lets say 7/22/2020, 100. What should I put into those 1, 1, 1,2 I dont understand those